# ARCore: Sceneform demo bug on loading asset from virtual device

Tags: java, android, 3d, augmented-reality, arcore

Hi and thanks in advance to anyone who can help me or give me some suggestions.

I was working on the Google ARCore demo, specifically the "`Hellosceneform`" one, where user can put a 3D model on a plane.

To test the import of different 3D assets, I changed the default "Andy" 3D model with another 3D model made by me, in the usual `.sfb` format and I tested the demo on Android Emulator.

The **problem** is this:

- if I load a 3D asset from the "`raw`" directory into the demo works perfectly...
- ...**BUT**, ***in the Android Emulator***, if I load an asset from a directory on the **device filesystem** (for example, the default `appath` of '`sceneform`' demo) the `ModelRenderable` (called `andyRenderable` in my code) in `onTapListener` **is always null!**

**More importantly**: the demo works perfectly on a real phone, in both situation (`raw` and device file system).

The code that loads the 3D asset is this:

```
    File fsfb = new File(local_path + "/" + "prova3.sfb");

    Uri usfb = Uri.fromFile(fsfb);
    ModelRenderable.builder()
            .setSource(this, usfb)
            .build()
            .thenAccept(renderable -> andyRenderable = renderable)
            .exceptionally(
                    throwable -> {
                        Toast toast =
                                Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to load andy renderable", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                        toast.show();
                        return null;
                    });
```

And the onTapListener code is this:

```
arFragment.setOnTapArPlaneListener(
            (HitResult hitResult, Plane plane, MotionEvent motionEvent) -> {

                if(nn >= 3 || andyRenderable == null)
                {
                    return;
                }
                nn++;
```

Comment: I am trying to load from storage/emulated/0/Downloads/andy.sfb
How can this be done . Meaning the default download folder
https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/issues/367

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

It was a matter of wrong permissions for the raw directory (it was impossible to load the model, it needed "`rw`" settings).